# How to edit machine hardware detail deployed by Juju?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I deployed Landscape's OpenStack Autopilot with Juju GUI on top of 6 KVM nodes. How do I edit the hardware detail in Juju GUI if I upgrade the node's RAM?

In the MaaS GUI, I can easily edit the CPU core, RAM size, and Storage size, but the Juju GUI still lists the machine with the old hardware details. How can I update or refresh the hardware details in Juju?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you will have to redeploy the service on that machine. Even in MAAS, it's usually best to recommission the node if its hardware changed.

Comment: Oh thanks. so I guess we could not upgrade the hardware once it's deployed by Juju. :)

Comment: Of course you can. There are several ways to address this. You could, with juju, move the service do another machine (juju add-unit, and then destroy the previous unit and recommission it in MAAS). Or if the service is running happily, there is no strict need for juju to know the hardware details of that particular node, because the service is already there. The hardware details are used when deciding where to place a unit of a service, given constraints that you set.